# How to use wildcards with ngrams in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to combine wildcard matches and ngrams in ElasticSearch? I'm already using ngrams of length 3-11.

As a very small example, I have records C1239123 and C1230123.  The user wants to return both of these.  This is the only info they know: C123?12

The above case won't work on my full match analyzer because the query is missing the 3 on the end. I was under the impression wildcard matches would work out of the box, but if I perform a search similar to the above I get gibberish.

Query:

```
.Search<ElasticSearchProject>(a => a
    .Size(100)
    .Query(q => q
        .SimpleQueryString(query => query
            .OnFieldsWithBoost(b => b
                .Add(f => f.Summary, 2.1)
                .Add(f => f.Summary.Suffix("ngram"), 2.0)
            .Query(searchQuery))));
```

Analyzer:

```
var projectPartialMatch = new CustomAnalyzer
{
    Filter = new List<string> { "lowercase", "asciifolding" },
    Tokenizer = "ngramtokenizer"
};
```

Tokenizer:

```
.Tokenizers(t=>t
    .Add("ngramtokenizer", new NGramTokenizer
    {
        TokenChars = new[] {"letter","digit","punctuation"},
        MaxGram = 11,
        MinGram = 3
    }))
```

EDIT:
The main purpose is to allow the user to tell the search engine exactly where the unknown characters are.  This preserves the match order.  I do not ngram the query, only the indexed fields.

EDIT 2 with more test results:
I had simplified my prior example a bit too much. The gibberish was being caused by punctuation filters. With a proper example there's no gibberish, but results aren't returned in a relevant order.  Seeing below, I'm unsure why the first 2 results match at all. Ngram is not applied to the query.

Searching for c.a123?.7?0 gives results in this order:

- C.A1234.560
- C.A1234.800
- C.A1234.700 <--Shouldn't this be first?
- C.A1234.950

Comment: Did you tried `c123?12*` ? It's fine to combine wildcard matches and ngrams in ElasticSearch but you must understand how it work. Otherwise it's return unexpected results

Comment: @Duc.Duong I have tried that. It does return results, but they appear to have no relevance to the query.

Comment: Can you post the matched results ? We can investigate more on it

Comment: @Duc.Duong I've added a new example.  It seems to work...somewhat. One wildcard seems fine. Multiple wildcards do not work well. One possibility that's seeming more likely is that since the data contains decimals to separate groups of numbers, applying to standard analyzer to the query might be interfering.

Comment: You can install `inquisitor` plugin to see the actual indexed data of `C.A1234.560`, `C.A1234.800` and maybe we can found some clues why it always matched. BTW it's good if you can write the scripts for create/index sample data/query into an SH file and post it to GIST, it will help me quickly run and check the issue. Otherwise can you post the final query that send to ES ? You can find it in  the search response of NEST

Answer (score 1):

To anyone looking for a resolution to this, wildcards are used on ngrammed tokens by default.  My problem was due to my queries having punctuation in them and using a standard analyzer on my query (which breaks on punctuation).

Duc.Duong's suggestion to use the Inquisitor plugin helped show exactly how data would be analyzed.